# Get a list of symbols from a string

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a big problem with my request. So for example I have the message:

```
@NM1@ Hello @NM2@ How @NM3@ are @NM4@ you
```

I want to extract:

```
@NM1@,@NM2@,@NM3@,@NM4@.
```

There can be multiple `@...@` expressions. Between @..@ can be not any character

I tried:

```
group_concat(regexp(em.value,'@[a-AA-Z0-9]*@'))
```

but no results.

Help me, please. Any ideas please!!!!!

Comment: Which dbms are you using? You tagged sql-server and sql-server 2008 but you have group_concat as what you tried??

Answer (score 0):

If this is supposed to be a PHP question, as stated, then the strings can be found like this:

```
<?php
    $string = "@NM1@Hello@NM2@How@NM3@are@NM4@you";

    preg_match_all('/@[A-Z]+[0-9]+/', $string, $matches);
    print(join(",", $matches[0]))."\n";
?>
```

Here I assume that there are alphabetic characters after the @, followed by numbers, so only the strings starting with NM in your example are matched.

If this is not, what you want, please be more specific.

Comment: Between @ and @ can be not import what

Comment: Don't understand what you are saying. Do you want *anything* between the @, not just the strings starting with NM and ending with numbers? So it would be NM1, Hello, NM2 ...

Comment: Ok, this is what is extracted here.

Comment: changed the output, so it exactly matches what you want

Answer (score 0):

if i understand you correctly-
use split function like this (or another one)-

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnSplitString] 
( 
    @string NVARCHAR(MAX), 
    @delimiter CHAR(1) 
) 
RETURNS @output TABLE(splitdata NVARCHAR(MAX) 
) 
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @start INT, @end INT 
    SELECT @start = 1, @end = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @string) 
    WHILE @start < LEN(@string) + 1 BEGIN 
        IF @end = 0  
            SET @end = LEN(@string) + 1

        INSERT INTO @output (splitdata)  
        VALUES(SUBSTRING(@string, @start, @end - @start)) 
        SET @start = @end + 1 
        SET @end = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @string, @start)

    END 
    RETURN 
END
```

and then use this code

```
SELECT left(splitdata,len(splitdata)-1) AS substr
INTO #x1
FROM [dbo].[fnSplitString] ('@NM1@ Hello @NM2@ How @NM3@ are @NM4@ you',' ')
WHERE splitdata LIKE '@%' AND splitdata LIKE '%@'
--SELECT * FROM #x1
GO
DECLARE   cur CURSOR FAST_FORWARD READ_ONLY
FOR SELECT substr
FROM #x1
DECLARE @str varchar(100)=''
DECLARE @i varchar(10)
OPEN cur
 FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @i

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0
BEGIN

SET @str = @str+@i+',' 
FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @i
END
CLOSE cur
DEALLOCATE cur
SELECT left(@str,len(@str)-1)
DROP table #x1
```